# uty4014 access module error 35 received during 'comm_pmreadddparse' operation:

Tags: teradata, mload

I'm new to mload. I get this error when I try to execute my mload script:

> uty4014 access module error 35 received during 'comm_pmreadddparse'
>   operation:'Unable to determine EOR for the datafile !ERROR! Could not
>   find a valid EOR'.

Also providing the mload script:

```
.logtable ALL_wkSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage_log;
.logmech ldap;
.logdata authcid= password=;
.LOGON tdip/; 
DROP Table ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage;
DROP Table ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.error_1;
DROP Table ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.error_2;
DROP Table ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage_WK;
CREATE SET TABLE ABCD_DB.Coverage
(
 COVG_KEY VARCHAR(50),
TRANSACTION_TYPE VARCHAR(20),
POLICY_NUMBER VARCHAR(18),
PRODUCER VARCHAR(17),
AGENT_NAME VARCHAR(64),
TRANSACTION_PROCESS_DATE VARCHAR(20),
ENDORSEMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE VARCHAR(10),
ENDORSEMENT_EXPIRATION_DATE VARCHAR(10),
POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE VARCHAR(10),
POLICY_EXPIRATION_DATE VARCHAR(10),
LINE_OF_BUSINESS VARCHAR(10),
STATE VARCHAR(2),
PREMIUM_AMOUNT VARCHAR(20),
COMPANY VARCHAR(32),
NAICS_CODE VARCHAR(6),
GL_CLASS_CODE VARCHAR(5),
BUSINESS_CLASS_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(64),
PARTY_NAME VARCHAR(64),
PARTY_TYPE_CD VARCHAR(16),
BUSINESS_PHONE VARCHAR(10),
BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_1 VARCHAR(64),
BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_2 VARCHAR(64),
BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_3 VARCHAR(32),
BL_COUNTRY VARCHAR(32),
BL_STATE VARCHAR(2),
BL_CITY VARCHAR(64),
BL_ZIP VARCHAR(10),
BL_COUNTY VARCHAR(32),
STATUS_CD VARCHAR(3),
QUOTE_CREATED_DATE VARCHAR(20)                  
);
.BEGIN IMPORT MLOAD TABLES ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage
    WORKTABLES ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage_WK
    ERRORTABLES ALL_wkSCRATCHPAD_DB.error_1
            ALL_wkSCRATCHPAD_DB.error_2
SESSIONS 5;
.LAYOUT  INPUT_RECORD;
.FIELD  COVG_KEY * VARCHAR(50);
.FIELD  TRANSACTION_TYPE * VARCHAR(20);
.FIELD  POLICY_NUMBER * VARCHAR(18);
.FIELD  PRODUCER * VARCHAR(17);
.FIELD  AGENT_NAME * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  TRANSACTION_PROCESS_DATE * VARCHAR(6);
.FIELD  ENDORSEMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  ENDORSEMENT_EXPIRATION_DATE * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  POLICY_EXPIRATION_DATE * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  LINE_OF_BUSINESS * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  STATE * VARCHAR(2);
.FIELD  PREMIUM_AMOUNT * VARCHAR(20);
.FIELD  COMPANY * VARCHAR(32);
.FIELD  NAICS_CODE * VARCHAR(6);
.FIELD  GL_CLASS_CODE * VARCHAR(5);
.FIELD  BUSINESS_CLASS_DESCRIPTION * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  PARTY_NAME * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  PARTY_TYPE_CD * VARCHAR(16);
.FIELD  BUSINESS_PHONE * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_1 * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_2 * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_3 * VARCHAR(32);
.FIELD  BL_COUNTRY * VARCHAR(32);
.FIELD  BL_STATE * VARCHAR(2);
.FIELD  BL_CITY * VARCHAR(64);
.FIELD  BL_ZIP * VARCHAR(10);
.FIELD  BL_COUNTY * VARCHAR(32);
.FIELD  STATUS_CD * VARCHAR(3);
.FIELD  QUOTE_CREATED_DATE * VARCHAR(10);
.DML LABEL insdml;
insert into ALL_WKSCRATCHPAD_DB.Coverage
(
COVG_KEY
,TRANSACTION_TYPE
,POLICY_NUMBER
,PRODUCER
,AGENT_NAME
,TRANSACTION_PROCESS_DATE
,ENDORSEMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE
,ENDORSEMENT_EXPIRATION_DATE
,POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE
,POLICY_EXPIRATION_DATE
,LINE_OF_BUSINESS
,STATE
,PREMIUM_AMOUNT
,COMPANY
,NAICS_CODE
,GL_CLASS_CODE
,BUSINESS_CLASS_DESCRIPTION
,PARTY_NAME
,PARTY_TYPE_CD
,BUSINESS_PHONE
,BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_1
,BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_2
,BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_3
,BL_COUNTRY
,BL_STATE
,BL_CITY
,BL_ZIP
,BL_COUNTY
,STATUS_CD
,QUOTE_CREATED_DATE
)
values
(
 :COVG_KEY
,:TRANSACTION_TYPE
,:POLICY_NUMBER
,:PRODUCER
,:AGENT_NAME
,:TRANSACTION_PROCESS_DATE
,:ENDORSEMENT_EFFECTIVE_DATE
,:ENDORSEMENT_EXPIRATION_DATE
,:POLICY_EFFECTIVE_DATE
,:POLICY_EXPIRATION_DATE
,:LINE_OF_BUSINESS
,:STATE
,:PREMIUM_AMOUNT
,:COMPANY
,:NAICS_CODE
,:GL_CLASS_CODE
,:BUSINESS_CLASS_DESCRIPTION
,:PARTY_NAME
,:PARTY_TYPE_CD
,:BUSINESS_PHONE
,:BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_1
,:BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_2
,:BL_STREET_ADDRESS_LINE_3
,:BL_COUNTRY
,:BL_STATE
,:BL_CITY
,:BL_ZIP
,:BL_COUNTY
,:STATUS_CD
,:QUOTE_CREATED_DATE
);
.IMPORT INFILE  '/home/adepum2/ABDC.txt'
FORMAT VARTEXT '|'
display errors
NOSTOP
LAYOUT INPUT_RECORD
APPLY insdml;
.END MLOAD;
.LOGOFF;
```

My txt file looks like:

> ||ACP 3008641853|00055050-140|JOHN RUSSELL MORAN|02/06/2018
>   08:52:00|||||GL||13538.00||||||||265 Buckingham
>   Ct|||||ILSchaumburg|601932084||||02/06/2018 08:33:00

I have tried to look for any Regex in my text file but not able to find it.

Your help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
phantom

Comment: EOR might be *End Of Record*, Unix `LF` vs Windows `CRLF`? But you shouldn't use legacy MLoad anymore, you better switch to TPT, your case is probably a simple task for the *Easy Loader*, `tdload`.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth,  but our company follows the legacy Mload.

Comment: Is there any other possible way to solve this issue.

Comment: I can't remember if I ever got this error, so I don't know how to fix it, sorry

Comment: Don't think you can specify a row delimiter in MLoad. Use your text editor of choice to see if your records end in LF (or something else) instead of CRLF.  Assuming so, use your script language of choice to replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. 
The issue was about the file type and also with the EOR it was LF not CRLF. I made changes to it and the only file type it was accepting was .DAT. I m not sure why the .DAT file type is being accepted only not the other types.

Thanks guys for your suggestions and spending your valuable time.